# Criei uma função de remover a ultima string porém esta bugado

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Estou criando uma calculadora e fiz a função de remover o ultimo numero digitado, porém esta ocorrendo um bug que se eu colocar para somar, subtrair, etc... com algo (antes de clicar no =) ele vai começar a retirar somente numeros iguais, por exemplo, digitei os seguintes numeros 12121212+12121212, vai retirar os 2 ultimos normalmente, porem a partir dai, vai começar a retirar somente os numeros 1, depois os numeros 2

Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Calculadora</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="calculadora container">
      
      <section class="resultado container">
        <section class="mode"></section>
        <input id="result" value="" type="text" readonly />
      </section>
      
      <div class="teclas container">
        <input type="button" value="x'" onclick="botao('**')" />
        <input type="button" id="del" value="DEL" onclick="retirar()" />
        <input type="button" value="%" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="C" onclick="limpar()" />
        <input type="button" value="7" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="8" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="9" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="x"
          onclick="botao('*')"
          class="operadores-basicos"
        />
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="5" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="6" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="-"
          onclick="botao(value)"
          class="operadores-basicos"
        />
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="/"
          onclick="botao(value)"
          class="operadores-basicos"
        />
        <input type="button" value="0" onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="." onclick="botao(value)" />
        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="calc()" id="igual" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="+"
          onclick="botao(value)"
          class="operadores-basicos"
        />
      </div>
    </main>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Meu JS:

```
const numeros = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const telaResultado = document.querySelector('#result')
const buttonDarkMode = document.querySelector('.mode')
let conta;

function botao(value) {
    conta = telaResultado.value += value
} 

function limpar() {
  telaResultado.value = ""
}

function calc() {

  const resultado = eval(conta)
  telaResultado.value = resultado
}

function retirar() {
  const palavraCompleta = telaResultado.value
  const ultimaLetra = palavraCompleta.substr(telaResultado.value.length-1)
  console.log(ultimaLetra)
  
  telaResultado.value = telaResultado.value.replace(ultimaLetra, "")
}

buttonDarkMode.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('ativo')
  buttonDarkMode.classList.toggle('ativo')
})
```

Lembrando, sou iniciante em js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Substitua o seu substr por um substring

```
 function retirar() {
      const palavraCompleta = telaResultado.value
      const ultimaLetra = palavraCompleta.substring(0, telaResultado.value.length - 1)
      console.log(ultimaLetra)
    
      telaResultado.value = ultimaLetra
    }
```

Comment: Fiz a substituição e o bug continua

Comment: Na verdade eu havia só substituido, o nome, copiei seu codigo e foi muito obrigado